# Load test spring-kafka consumer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka for writing producers and consumers.
Can someone please help with how to load test consumer?
I am aware of kafka-perf-test-x scripts but these are cli tools that does only producing and consuming messages.
My consumer does a lot more than just consuming a message, I want to load test my consumer. Please help on this.